# Utilizing Pin/Password already built into android

Tags: android, security

Is it possible to use the built in PIN/Password/Pattern in android for Android applications?

For instance, if a pin were set on the phone...it could be used to unlock an application. Otherwise, the user would have to set a pin for the application and/or phone.

Comment: If the user has unlocked their phone, why would they also need to unlock the application?

Comment: A current project I am working on has a requirement to 'login' to the application. It confuses me, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so and I hope they don't add one.

There are [trusted path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_path) issues with allowing apps to request entry of the user's PIN.

The phone needs to make sure that apps don't keylog and exfiltrate PINs or administrative passwords, so user's need to be trained to only enter their PIN/password into a user-interface that sends events only to the OS.  This is similar to the way that the Windows login is only displayed after Ctrl-Alt-DEL, a key sequence that is guaranteed to remove window focus and so stop the flow of key events to user-ring code.

Even providing an API that allows applications to request that the user confirm their administrative secrets weakens security by training users to enter important secrets in a variety of situations instead of only after Ctrl-Alt-DEL or other OS trapped sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely make your own, but I don't think you can utilize the one from the OS.